# Amazon Container Registry Only with ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

Is ECR only working with ECS or is it possible to use it in a 'custom' docker-swarm/docker-machine deployment to EC2 or other vendors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this, its not limited to ECS:

> Amazon ECR is a regional service and is designed to give you
>   flexibility in how images are deployed. You have the ability to
>   push/pull images to the same region where your Docker cluster runs for
>   the best performance. ***You can also access Amazon ECR anywhere that
>   Docker runs such as desktops and on-premises environments***. Pulling
>   images between regions or out to the internet will have additional
>   latency and data transfer costs.

https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/faqs/